# How to correctly set the Typescript type of the result returned by the dispatch method in redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

`fetchSomething` is defined like this:

```js
export const fetchSomething = createAsyncThunk(
  'something',
  async () => {
    return Promise.resolve({name: 'jack'})
  }
)
```

Here's the code inside the React component:

```js
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

const getMessages = async () => {
  const result = await dispatch(fetchSomething())
  return result.payload
}
```

`result` has the correct Typescript type, while `result.payload` is of type `unknown`

```js
const result: PayloadAction<{name: string}, string, {arg: void, requestId: string, requestStatus: "fulfilled"}, never> | PayloadAction<unknown, string, {arg: void, requestId: string, requestStatus: "rejected", aborted: boolean, condition: boolean}, SerializedError>
```

I found related information on [official documentation](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-redux-thunks), but I don't know how to use in my example:

```js
import { UnknownAction } from 'redux'
import { sendMessage } from './store/chat/actions'
import { RootState } from './store'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

export const thunkSendMessage =
  (message: string): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, UnknownAction> =>
  async dispatch => {
    const asyncResp = await exampleAPI()
    dispatch(
      sendMessage({
        message,
        user: asyncResp,
        timestamp: new Date().getTime()
      })
    )
  }

function exampleAPI() {
  return Promise.resolve('Async Chat Bot')
}
```

I want the `getMessages` method to return the correct type `Promise<{name: string}>`

I queried the docs again as suggested by @timotgl, found this [section](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-thunkapi-object), and made changes to the code, but the problem persists, The type of `result.payload` is still `unknown`.

```js
export const fetchSomething = createAsyncThunk<{name: string}>(
  'something',
  async () => {
    return Promise.resolve({name: 'jack'})
  }
)
```

Comment: It's the second generic type argument for `createAsyncThunk` I think, so you'd write `createAsyncThunk<TypeOfArgument,TypeOfResolvedValue>()` to instruct TS to know this. It helps if you configure your editor/IDE to show you tooltips/autocompletion for this.

Comment: `return result.payload as Promise<{ name: string }>;`?

Comment: @DrewReese I know this method, but I don't want to use it because it's like a trick

Comment: @timotgl Could you please explain in more detail, such as posting the code.

Comment: @SageJustus I did, the part inside the `<>` are the type arguments.

Comment: @timotgl I modified the code as you said, added in the question details, please check if it is correct.

Comment: @SageJustus I remembered it wrong, see the answer below by DrewReese. createAsyncThunk only has one type argument, for the type of the inner function's argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Basic `createAsyncThunk` Types](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#basic-createasyncthunk-types):

> In the most common use cases, you should not need to explicitly
> declare any types for the createAsyncThunk call itself.
>
> Just provide a type for the first argument to the payloadCreator
> argument as you would for any function argument, and the resulting
> thunk will accept the same type as its input parameter. The return
> type of the payloadCreator will also be reflected in all generated
> action types.
>
> ```
> interface MyData {
>   // ...
> }
>
> const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
>   'users/fetchById',
>   // Declare the type your function argument here:
>   async (userId: number) => {
>     const response = await fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${userId}`)
>     // Inferred return type: Promise<MyData>
>     return (await response.json()) as MyData // <--
>   }
> )
>
> // the parameter of `fetchUserById` is automatically inferred to `number` here
> // and dispatching the resulting thunkAction will return a Promise of a correctly
> // typed "fulfilled" or "rejected" action.
> const lastReturnedAction = await store.dispatch(fetchUserById(3))
> ```

Take note of the thunk's return value:

```js
// Inferred return type: Promise<MyData>
return (await response.json()) as MyData
```

Applying the above suggested pattern to your code:

```js
interface Something {
  name: string;
};

export const fetchSomething = createAsyncThunk(
  'something',
  async () => {
    return Promise.resolve({ name: 'jack' }) as Something;
  }
)
```

```js
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

const getMessages = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await dispatch(fetchSomething()).unwrap();
    return result;
  } catch(error) {
    // ... any error handling logic ...
  }
};
```

Comment: I got it, the key is to use `unwrap()`.